# RHEL 7.9 + microcode_ctl + warning in kernel messages

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, dmesg, dracut

I want to share the following issue

after upgrading the security rpm's on RHEL 7.9 machines include update of `microcode_ctl` rpm

```
rpm -qa | grep microcod
microcode_ctl-2.1-73.15.el7_9.x86_64
```

we noticed about the following kernel messages.

```
[Sun Jun  4 13:12:19 2023] Microcode update for Intel Broadwell-EP/EX (BDX-ML B/M/R0; family 6, model 79,
stepping 1; CPUID 0x406f1) CPUs is disabled as it may cause system instability.
Please refer to /usr/share/doc/microcode_ctl/caveats/06-4f-01_readme
and /usr/share/doc/microcode_ctl/README.caveats for details.
[Sun Jun  4 13:13:35 2023] After installation of a new version of microcode_ctl package,
[Sun Jun  4 13:13:35 2023] initramfs hasn't been re-generated for all the installed kernel packages.
[Sun Jun  4 13:13:35 2023] The following kernel packages have been skipped: kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64.
[Sun Jun  4 13:13:35 2023] Please re-generate initramfs manually for these kernel packages with the
[Sun Jun  4 13:13:35 2023] "dracut -f --kver KERNEL_VERSION" command in order to get the latest
[Sun Jun  4 13:13:35 2023] Intel CPU microcode included into early initramfs image for it, if needed.
```

the current RHEL kernel version is

```
uname -r
3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
```

so according to dmesg we can see that.

```
dracut -f --kver KERNEL_VERSION
```

so is it means that we need to set the current kernel version in command as

```
dracut -f --kver 3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
```

or to set the kernel as defined in kernel message as

```
dracut -f --kver  kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says

> The following kernel packages have been skipped: kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64.
> Please re-generate initramfs manually for these kernel packages with the
> "dracut -f --kver KERNEL_VERSION" command in order to get the latest
> Intel CPU microcode included into early initramfs image for it, if needed.

It asks you to re-generate the initramfs for version 3.10.0-514.26.2:

```
dracut -f --kver 3.10.0-514-26.2
```

You only need to do this if you plan on switching back to 514 instead of your current 1160.

Comment: actually, we want to stay with current kernel version - 3.10.0-1160 , we not want  to use the previous  kernel version 514 , so in that case I assume we not need to do any action?

Comment: That’s exactly what I wrote: “You only need to do this if you plan on switching back to 514 instead of your current 1160.”

Comment: may I ask why kernel concerned about 3.10.0-514-26.2 version if the current version is 3.10.0-1160 ?

Comment: Because it is still installed, and the update check looks at all installed versions, not just the currently-booted version.